# Parellel.ForEach error

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library

I have an array of threads which i want run in simultaneous/parallel but i get "`NullReferenceException`"

```
var t = new Thread[6];
t[0] = new Thread(() => DoSomething0());
t[1] = new Thread(() => DoSomething1());
t[2] = new Thread(() => DoSomething2());
t[3] = new Thread(() => DoSomething3());
t[4] = new Thread(() => DoSomething4());
t[5] = new Thread(() => DoSomething5());
Parallel.ForEach(t, item => item.Start());
```

It gives error at `Parrallel.Foreach` because item is `null` but what am i doing wrong?

Comment: It might be because you are setting up the thread to a size of 6, but only filling 5 slots.

Comment: no thats an edit mistake

Comment: Why are you using a `Parrallel.Forech` to start threads?  The overhead of doing that in parallel would take more time then just calling start on each in a sequential foreach loop.

Comment: Arrays in C# are ZERO Based..! define it as `var t = new Thread[5];` should correct your problem..

Comment: Bassically i would like to have all operations run in the same time thats why i choosed parallel.foreach

Comment: indeed one of them was null im stupid

Comment: Since your spawning threads, you are already doing what you need to get them to run at the same time.  If you want to use `Parallel.Foreach` it would make more sense to add the actions you want to perform to a list, then invoke those actions in the `Parallel.Foreach`

Comment: @adisba They will run in different threads as a result of the fact that you're manually starting different threads for each one.  `Start` isn't blocking.  If you just start each task in a non-parallel `foreach` loop they'll still do all of their work in parallel.

Comment: why put it in a list instead of array?

Comment: @adisba Either list or array would work.

Comment: Don't change the question to match the answers - now none of the answers make sense.

Comment: i didn't change the question to match the answers i already said it was an edit problem and already said

Comment: So you still have the problem?

Comment: No but how to close question?

Answer (score 1):

You create an array for six items, but you only assign values to the first five. The last item is null, so you get a null reference error when you try to use all items in the array.

Answer (score 1):

You defined 6 elements but you assign only 5 elements, last element is `null` now.

That's why you get `NullReferanceException` when you try to use all of them.

Initialize also 6th element.

```
t[0] = new Thread(() => DoSomething0());
t[1] = new Thread(() => DoSomething1());
t[2] = new Thread(() => DoSomething2());
t[3] = new Thread(() => DoSomething3());
t[4] = new Thread(() => DoSomething4());
t[5] = new Thread(() => DoSomething5());
```

Answer (score 1):

You have an array instantiated with 6 slots (all initially `null`), and you only instantiate the first 5 slots, leaving the 6th `null`. This would be your null item.